# how could I SUM every children in a tree with java recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, parent-child

So there's the mission. We have a class, call "Node", the instance is "node". This node has a lot of children, and these children have a lot of children too, etc etc. How could I SUM the all children number in this tree? example:

- node -> child1 -> child1.1 -> child1.1.1, child 1.1.2 -> child1.1.2.1
- node -> child2
- node -> child3 -> child3.1, child3.2 -> child3.2.1

the number of the all children is 10 (node is the parent). please help me someone, and write the current answer with java recursion. The program should start with:

```
public int childrenNumber(Node node){...
```

Comment: Can you show some code?? Your question is very Vague..

Comment: `public class Node{ List<Node> getChildren(){...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a function that's a member of your node class.
2. In the function, set a count variable to 1 (for this node).
3. Loop though all of this node's children. Add to the count variable the result of calling this function on each child node.
4. Return the count variable.

Now, to get the total number of nodes in the tree, call the count function on the root node.

Comment: `public class Node{ List<Node> getChildren(){...}` could you write a code please?

Comment: Only if you split your grade with me.

Comment: `public int sum(Node node){
  int sum=1;
  for(Node child: node.getChildren()){
    sum+=sum(child);
  }
  return sum;
}` is it correct?

Comment: Try it and see. If so, celebrate. If not, debug it. I can't test it since I don't have the code you're working on.

Comment: ok, thank you so much! anyway i don't have code, it is a sample test in a java interview